# Wait for Redux action to dispatch a second one

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Hi and thanks in advance for reading my question.

I am working on a React app (version 16) with router v3 and Redux.

The app has an structure similar to this:

```
<Route path="/" component={BakeryComponent}>
  <IndexRoute component={LandingComponent}/>
  <Route path="employees" component={EmployeesComponent}/>
  <Route path="clients" component={ClientComponent}/>
</Route>
```

So we have like different entities. Bakery which is the main one, employees that depends on the selected bakery and clients which also depends on the bakery.

When we access the app we land on the landing page which shows general info of the bakery (there is one by default selected) like name, employees quantity and some other. All that info comes from the backend, it is retrieved in the componentDidMount of either Bakery or Landing component (at this point it does not make any difference).

When the user is in the landing page he can navigates to either employees or clients views. When that happens the component is mounted, let's suppose it is employees component, and in the component's componentDidMount method we retrieve the needed information (the employees list in this case).

Everything works fine until now.

Now, if the user refreshes the page everything should still works (it is a requirement) but it doesn't. The problem is that when that happens BakeryComponent and EmployeesComponent (both of them) are mounted again, so new backends calls are triggered (in parallel). But the backend call to employees depends on bakery to be resolved first because we need to know the employees of what bakery we want, so we get an error at thi point.

I tried to check in the invoked action (the one to retrieve the employees) if the bakery was already resolve (using getState) and if not, wait for it to be resolved. But it does not convince me, it looks kind of a hack. I have the feeling that React/Redux should already have the tools to solve this but I just don't know them. Am I right?

Any help will be really helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: Check this out - [Redux Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html). Or more specifically, [Async Action Creators](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators).

Comment: Thanks, but I already did read those two links. My problem is not Async Actions, my problem is that I need to serialize them someway I think, I am not sure though.

Comment: If you need the response from the first api call, for the second api call, then async actions will solve that problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time. Maybe it's me that do not see the solution. I know I can do what you say by returning a promise from inside a thunk action, in that case the return value of the first dispatch would be a promise I can wait for before dispatching the second action. But in my case, the first action and the second are made in different components, so the second one cannot access the promise of the first one. Or maybe I do not see how.

Comment: why dont you put the selected value into sessionstorage or local storage

Comment: or use SFcookie to save the state to cookie

Comment: Or store the result of the first api call in your redux store. Connect the component with the second api call: `SecondApiComponent = connect((state) => ({firstApiResponse: state.whereEverYouStoredFirstApiResponse}))(SecondApiComponent);`. Then you can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method of class components to check if the your `firstApiResponse` prop has changed, and if it has and is valid, fire off the second api call. [React-redux: connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a way for you, although It's actually not a cool solution. You can check if the data in the BakeryComponent is ready or not before calling dispatch in the LandingComponent. Something like this:

BakeryComponent

```
componentDidMount() {
  // after this one finish we may have something in the store like: state.bakery.loaded = true   
  dispatch(loadBakery()) 
}
```

LandingComponent

```
// Landing component should connect to state.bakery.loaded to get updated data
componentDidMount() {
  initData()
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  initData()
}

initData() {
  // check if bakery loaded and landing data is not loaded
  if (state.bakery.loaded && !state.landing.loaded) {
    // this should load data and set the state.landing.loaded to true
    dispatch(loadLanding())
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments from Sujit.Warrier and the last comment from Kyle Richardson in my original question are also useful but I will select this answer as 'the answer' because it works, it is pure React (do not need for local storage for instance) and shows effort from the author.